# Ajax sync or async

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two ajax calls. Both are sync. Both call methods from one controller. But the second method gets hit first. Why is this and how to change it?

Comment: Call first method, *wait* for response, call second method?

Comment: elaborate it completely means how you send request please tell us story.

Comment: `I have two ajax calls. Both are sync` That's interesting, because AJAX calls are by theyre nature asynchronous. Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As name said Ajax - **Asynchronous JavaScript**

Ajax is async

---

**Edit**

For you question you can do like calling second URL on response of first one, A simple jQuery example is,

```
/*First request*/
$.post("{SOME_URL}", { PARAMS },
    function(data) {
        /*Do anything with data*/
        /*Your second request*/
        $.post("{SOME_URL}", { PARAMS },
            function(data) {
                /*Do anything with data*/
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Moreover jQuery supports **async** flag that can be set to false to activate Asynchronous nature of the query. But this will block all other request from same page.

Please read more on this [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: but we can also send sync call through ajax

Comment: That is only done on browser side by blocking other request. Where as at core Ajax async. You have to manage server code for same.

Comment: Not only blocking requests. `async` blocks execution of **all** scripts, even in different tabs, i.e. it block entire browser. **Do not use it - it's a satan!** :D

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated. So beware of that also